# Phonegap/cordova cant able to locate the email attachement file

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap

I am developing a phonegap app/cordova app for displaying the files on the screen,I have .true file in which it contains the image of a file in json format.I was trying to the display the images from the .true file on the app screen,but i can able to locate the file even though i could open with my application

[My application need to detect the ".true" file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdMKe.png)

[![][2]][2]

[![][3]

If i am opening here the file is actually taking to the app,but i cant able to open in the app,because i cant see in the downloads directory the file which i opened from the email attachement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For receiving data from other Applications to your application we need to use web-intent ,You can download the plugin from this link 
https://github.com/GroupAhead/cordova-plugin-webintent

Use this code in your document device

```
window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function(url) {
if(url !== "") {
    // url is the url the intent was launched with
    $('p').html(url+"printing");
    alert("hi");
    alert(url);

}
});
```

the url is where the intent is launched and from the url you can access the file